# Saving values from recordset

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am getting the values by getfieldvalue function from access db. I need to save bunch of those values and then do the calculation with those values. What's the best way ?
Thanks for help. If there is some info missing please let me know. I'll try to provide.
Thank You again

```
CRecordset rset(&pdatabase);

        if(rset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, selectionStr))
        {
            while(rset.IsBOF()&&rset.IsEOF())
            {
                m_Log->Log("Copying Previous Values from Access DB");
                rset.GetFieldValue((short)0 ,pname_old);
                rset.GetFieldValue((short)1 ,Date_old);
                rset.GetFieldValue((short)2 ,Time_old);
                rset.GetFieldValue((short)3 ,Y_old));
                rset.GetFieldValue((short)4 ,QTime_old);

            }

            rset.MoveNext();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tool from the stl, like [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) to handle your datas while getting them, and treat them after your collection.

Comment: I am looking for the least code and efficient way. Can i save them like a set or some thing?

Comment: Stl tools are designed as template, so they can store everything without much issues if your classes are canonical.
I'd suggest you to use vector if you know how many datas you are collection, list if not. Don't hesitate to quickly read the doc i gave you by links, those sites really explain quickly how to use it, and how much time/memory it costs.

Comment: But each one of them are in a single row in the db. On any given date i get all the five values and i write all of them in the db in a single row. Now when i want to copy all of them into my program i want to keep that mapping between those variable. How can i do this?

Comment: Youo could design a object to tore your data, like a structure with 5 variables to handle the whole row you are currently viewing.

Comment: Sure, i don't really know what you are trying to store, but what about this ?
`struct s_data
{
int pname_old;
int date_old;
int time_old;
int y_old;
int qtime_old;
}`

Feel free to replace int by the correct types, and good luck !

Comment: Thank You. This struct can save multiple rows as well?

Comment: No, you will need to use one of the containters i suggest you to stock the structures one by one. You really should read the links i gave you, these are very easy to understand with the documentation !